# MongoDB - Copy field to another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have collection `orders`:

```
[
  {
     "id":"1",
     "items":{
        "itemId":"1000",
        "name":"Item 1",
        "status":"STATUS"
     }
  },
  {
     "id":"2",
     "items":{
        "itemId":"1000",
        "name":"Item 1",
        "status":"ANOTHER_STATUS"
     }
  }
]
```

I have another collection `item_projections` which is

```
[
  {
     "id":"1",
     "itemId":"1000",
     "name":"Item 1",
     "orderId":"1"
  },
  {
     "id":"1",
     "itemId":"1000",
     "name":"Item 1",
     "orderId":"2"
  }
]
```

For every item from collection `orders` I would like to copy the field `status` to projection with matching on order `id` and `itemId` to have

```
[
  {
     "id":"1",
     "itemId":"1000",
     "name":"Item 1",
     "orderId":"1",
     "status":"STATUS"
  },
  {
     "id":"1",
     "itemId":"1000",
     "name":"Item 1",
     "orderId":"2",
     "status":"ANOTHER_STATUS"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to do it with aggregation lookup and merge pipelines?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

1. `$lookup` - `item_projections` collection (key: `orderId`) join `orders` collection (key: `id`) and return `orders` array field with the document(s) of `status` field only.
2. `$replaceRoot` - Replace input document with new document.

   2.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge root document with the first document of `orders`.
3. `$unset` - Remove `orders` field.

```
db.item_projections.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "localField": "orderId",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $project: {
            status: "$items.status"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $first: "$orders"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "orders"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/19hND-x1G8W)

---

**Solution 2**

Or you can replace the 2nd and 3rd stages with `$project`.

```
{
  $project: {
    "id": 1,
    "itemId": 1,
    "name": 1,
    "orderId": 1,
    "status": {
      $first: "$orders.status"
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G9g3Kpkba0b)